# What is the differences between the two versions of these myths?

Tags: greek, interpretation

What is the differences between the two versions of these myths? How can they be interpreted? The first image is a Bell crater by a Berlin painter in Tarquinia (Italy), Museum. C. 490 BC, it has detail with Zeus and Europa.The next image pertains to Europa and is a wall painting in Naples, National Museum(from Pompeii (IX,5,18)). I understand they both have ties to Europa but I want to identify the differences between the intended versions of the myth. How can each of them be interpreted possibly differently? I have recently been interested in Greek Art and want to learn more about these specific pieces as I believe they can be very much related to one another but there much be differences? [image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. They both depict Zeus and Europa. Are you perhaps referring to the three women in the painting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, none.

Both paintings show that Zeus led Europa away in the form of a bull.

The only difference I can make between those paintings are the fact that the first one is only Europa is the only one, while the second, she is with her friends, being misled by Zeus.

Comment: Good answer. Just a quick follow up that you might want to clarify:  are the women standing next to Europa in the picture here friends or her handmaidens?

Comment: Dunno. Maybe ask a question on that?